# Nested field limit in ES 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I make number of nested fields unlimited on single index using index setting? I think its irrelevant to give nested field limit value since we don't have time to count number of nested field which goes on increasing as time passes.

Comment: You should explain in a bit more details what your use case is, maybe give one or two examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have to run mapping over index for around 20 record type which contain  more than 50 nested field.I increased value with PUT localhost:9200/1000/_settings
{
   "index.mapping.nested_fields.limit": 1001
} Instead of giving 1001 can i make it unlimited?

Comment: Of course you can but that will limit the scalability of your indices. [There is a reason](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14983) why this limit has been created.

Comment: Could you please tell me technique to make nested field limit unlimited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the source code of [`MapperService.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/6ea89004cded88ca4d0ab9cd96c7c44057e47b4f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/MapperService.java#L89), the `INDEX_MAPPING_NESTED_FIELDS_LIMIT_SETTING` constant is of type `long` so in theory "unlimited" would mean `Long.MAX_VALUE` (=2^63-1)

So even though it's not a good idea, you could do it like this:

```
PUT localhost:9200/1000/_settings
{ "index.mapping.nested_fields.limit": 9223372036854775807 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I m just curious to know technique to make nested field limit unlimited.

Comment: I think you're safe and you'll never reach that maximum long value :)

Comment: While writing on ES through hadoop job ,it freezes with logs as :Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene,What might be the reason?

Comment: That's probably not related to the same problem, or is it?

Comment: Its issue due to ES upgrade to 2.3.3.I think its dependency problem .Anyways thanks.